# Rails 4 Routes Params Optionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing

How do a route like this?

```
www.site.com/clothing/men/T-Shirts_type/Nike_brand/100-500_price/Red,White,Blue_color/
www.site.com/clothing/woman/Nike_brand/100-500_price/Red,White,Blue_color/
```

Should always be in order:

```
www.site.com/Sex/Type/Brand/Price/Color
```

Even if not insert all the available options:

```
www.site.com/Type/Color
```

The idenficador would always `_something`.

And the **comma** to enter more than one item.

**EDIT 01**

I need routes understand Value_something. 
And return like that:

```
param[:_something] = Values
```

Ex: 01 - One attribute

```
URL: site.com/clothing/men/T-Shirts_type
param[:_type] = T-Shirts
```

Ex: 02 - Two attributes

```
URL: site.com/clothing/men/T-Shirts_type/Nike_brand
param[:_type] = T-Shirts
param[:_brand] = Nike
```

Ex: 03 - Two attributes without order

```
URL: site.com/clothing/men/Nike_brand/T-Shirts_type
param[:_brand] = Nike
param[:_type] = T-Shirts
```

Ex: 04 - Multiple params in attribute

```
URL: site.com/clothing/men/Red,White,Blue_color
param[:_color] = Red,White,Blue
```

Ex: 05 - All attributes with order

```
URL: site.com/clothing/men/T-Shirts_type/Nike_brand/100-500_price/Red,White_color
param[:_type] = T-Shirts
param[:_brand] = Nike
param[:_price] = 100-500
param[:_color] = Red,White
```

Ex: 05 - All attributes without order

```
URL: site.com/clothing/men/Red,White_color/T-Shirts_type/100-500_price/Nike_brand
param[:_color] = Red,White
param[:_type] = T-Shirts
param[:_price] = 100-500
param[:_brand] = Nike
```

Comment: couldnt understand your question. what do you want to do?

Comment: I wonder if you could be leveraging an existing e-commerce platform like [Spree](http://spreecommerce.com/) rather than coding these things from scratch. I don't imagine this is the first e-commerce-specific challenge you'll run into, and I imagine most of these problems have likely already been solved by someone else.

Comment: @JasonSwett I will not create an e-commerce system, this was just an example. If yes, would use a ready-made service for sure. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that the route parser can do clever processing like this, ie to split the components up, use the first part of the split as a param name, and the last part as a value.  You need to do that in the controller, though you could have a before filter to do it, if this is going to be done in a lot of different actions.

Comment: See the edit to my answer, for converting the path fragments to params.

Comment: thanks.  I still think you should just have them in the params in the first place, rather than the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom route for each of the different cases. eg

```
#in config/routes.rb
get '/clothing/:sex/:option1/:option2/:option3/:option4/:option5', to: 'product#index'
get '/clothing/:sex/:option1/:option2/:option3/:option4', to: 'product#index'
get '/clothing/:sex/:option1/:option2/:option3', to: 'product#index'
get '/clothing/:sex/:option1/:option2', to: 'product#index'
get '/clothing/:sex/:option1', to: 'product#index'
```

Then in your index action you'll want to do something like

```
options = [params[:option1], params[:option2], params[:option3], params[:option4], params[:option5]].reject(&:blank?)
condition_strings = ["sex = #{params[:sex]}"]
options.each do |option_string|
  choices, category = option_string.split(" ")
  condition_strings << "#{category} in (#{choices})"
end
conditions = condition_strings.map{|string| "(#{string})"}.join(" AND ")
@products = Product.find(:all, :conditions => [conditions])
```

That said, i think this is a really horrible url schema.  I would think it would be better to have all the different options as parameters rather than part of the path itself, eg have urls like

www.site.com/clothing?gender=men&type=T-Shirts&brand=Nike&price=100-500&color=Red,White,Blue

This is a much more conventional way of doing things.

EDIT - a rewrite of the above controller-side processing, to make the params structure you want:

```
options = [params[:option1], params[:option2], params[:option3], params[:option4], params[:option5]].reject(&:blank?)
options.each do |option_string|
  choices, category = option_string.split("_")
  params[category] = choices
end
```

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. Can exemplify this format?